# Calling Sub from Public Class

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I've got this code:

```
  Public Class Events

        Inherits MyModule
        Private myTag As MyPoint
        'Call Calculations() here!


        Public Overrides Sub Calculations()
         'Do stuff with myTag
        End Sub
    End Class
```

As commented, I need to call Calculations() from class Events. I tried     `Dim mycalc As New Calculations()` but I get

```
Type 'Calculations' is not defined.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
Dim mycalc As New Calculations()
```

You're not trying to call the `Calculations` method.  You're trying to instantiate the `Calculations` *class*.  It's not a class, hence the error.

You need to create an instance of the class and then call the method on that instance.  Something like this:

```
Dim myEvents As New Events()
myEvents.Calculations()
```

Conversely, if you're trying to call the method from *within* the `Events` class, you can just call it directly (since the current class instance is already defined):

```
Calculations()
```